# My WAMP Server is not working after fresh installation?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

The port is clear, and I have Skype listening on a different port, I just installed WAMP and I have attempted to restart the server.

The tray icon is perpetually RED despite me restarting and starting.

The error Google Chrome sends me when I attempt to visit localhost is: `Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.`

Any input as to go about getting WAMP working?

Comment: Try [SE Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Uninstalling wamp doesn't uninstall all of the components, uninstall wamp then php, then anything else that is left, then re-install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely port 80 is already in use. You'll have to open your httpd.conf file and change

```
Listen 80
```

to something else like

```
Listen 8080
```

Start your server and then instead of navigating to

```
http://localhost/
```

navigate to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: As a side note, I like AMMPS way better than WAMP

Answer (score 1):

1. have a look into Windows Event log
2. use a portscanner that dedects other services listening on port 80 (I think wampserver and xampp do have such a tool included)
3. have a look into apache log
4. check your local windows firewall

Answer (score 1):

- Stop WAMP
- `netstat -ano|find ":80"` in command-line
- look for port 80 in the left column, and the PID in the right column
- look up the pid on the right in your running services (Task Manager) to determine which application is using port 80
- You may need to go to "View" -> "Select columns..." and check "PID"