# wamp server cannot open Localhost

Tags: php, wampserver

I am new in php and now i installed wampserver 2.2 application and when i click to Localhost option, the "Unable to connect" page shown in my Firefox browser.

this is my www folder:

[image]

And this is my `index.php` file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>  Hello To PHP Learning! </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    echo  'Hello World';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "when i click to Localhost option, the "Unable to connect" page shown!" - huh?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath my browser can not open my `index.php` file.

Comment: Sounds like the wamp server is not running, not installed correctly, or firewalled.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think he talk about the icon in status bar, (localhost item menu)

Comment: @Jahnux73 my icon in status bar is orange!

Comment: Orange : your server in not running correctly... you may have a conflict...

Comment: @Jahnux73 What should do?

Comment: Maybe you have a conflict with another running server ? I think you should have problem about your 80 port.

Comment: @Jahnux73 i don't use skype , What is ASP?

Comment: You should look for similar wamp problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17301439/2454790

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed the `C++ Redistributable Package` ?

You should install it before installing wamp!

Answer (score 2):

Did you Tried

> 127.0.0.1

instead of localhost

1. IIS and Apache/Wamp are both web server and might conflict in some way, so you have to disable IIS in order for Wamp to work

Disable IIS :
Control Panel, Uninstall Programs, Turn Widows Features On or Off, uncheck Internet Information Services

1. if using skype, open skype > tools > options > connections > advanced > untick "use port 80 ..." then restart wamp then skype
2. There might be port problem in httpd.conf change it to 80 instead of other
   ON LINE NO 40+

> LISTEN 80

OR TRY TO CONNECT

- The last but not least method

Try to uninstall WAMP Server and reinstall it in another Drive except same drive.

Comment: turn off skype, then restart wamp - worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your wamp server should be started (green icon in the tray), the Apache and PHP services should be ON.

In most of the cases wamp server launches Apache on default 80 port, which might be used (for example from Skype) when you try to start Apache, so kill processes that listen on port 80 before launching wamp.

Comment: My wampserver icon is orange, What should do?

Comment: What I said. Kill processes that listen on this port. Or, open your config file and change the port. But, if you change the Apache port, you will need to call the localhost as `http://localhost:newPort` where `newPort` is the port you said to it.

Comment: How kill process that listen to this port? what port?

Comment: You seem to NOT read my answer. It is port `80`. And a simple google search `kill processes port 80 windows` would help you. `netstat -a -b` in the command line should list you the processes and ports. Find ones from port 80 and kill them via task manager. But it most of the cases it's skype. Just quit Skype, and restart WAMP

Answer (score 0):

Causes for ’404 error in wamp server’:
This problem happening for Port issue. You may be install some services which one taking Port 80. Like,

Skype
IIS Express Web Server
Some Torrent Clients
Teamviewer
...
So only ‘HTTP 404 error page not found’ happening.

Solution:

You have to change your wamp server Port number. Just do following simple steps,

Open httpd.conf file
After run your wamp server, left click taskbar Wamp green icon. Then go-to Apache->httpd.conf

(Otherwise open like: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf )

Change Listen 80
There, Line number 46 having “Listen 80″.
Just replace 80 as “81″ like
     Listen 81

Change ServerName localhost:80
And Line number 171 having “ServerName localhost:80″.
Just replace with same number as you used Line number 46. Like,
     ServerName localhost:81
And save this file.

Use URL
Just restart your Apache or Wamp then use URL like following,
localhost:81 or
127.0.0.0:81 ( here 127.0.0.0: is your wamp IP )

localhost:81